# Angularjs deployment strategy

Tags: angularjs, versioning, continuous-deployment

How can I deploy and Angularjs app and ensure that all my users get the update when it happens? I have a breaking change that needs to be deployed and would cause some downstream issues should a user continue using the old version. Are there any tools or best practices on how to handle this?

Comment: your app is in http-server dont you ? . so when you make changes and substitue the older version, when clients reload page or refresh they will get the updates.

Comment: I already do that, but a lot of users keep the app open for long periods of time which would allow them to talk to the back end API while on an older version of the app. I am hoping to find a way to seamlessly update the app so the user doesn't end up at dead ends

Comment: why not use session if session is ended. reload the app.

Comment: A client requested feature was to allow long sessions, we have users that keep their browser open for days.

Comment: well there will be many alterantives you can do. i will put some in the anwers, comment in there.

Comment: In your front, you could set timer to keep checking on server side, if client/server version is different from server/client side, you can popup a message that the version of server/client side is updated and should reload page or like that.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comments says you cant do it with session expires, one alternative you can do, its handle in the backend to check if an update was release and with push notifications cand inform to client. Forcing to reload the app.

An intrusive will do the same thing but without notification, only if response tell there is an update reload page, according api response.